# Faster creation of small numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a code where I need to do some operation on a small number of inputs and return the result in a numpy array. The problem is that the actual creation of the numpy array takes much longer than the operation itself. My question is whether it is possible to somehow speed up the creation of the new array.

As an example, consider the following:

```
def return_list(x1, x2, x3):
     return [x1**2, x2**2, x3**2]

def return_array(x1, x2, x3):
    return np.array([x1**2, x2**2, x3**2])
```

Profiling the code:

```
%prun for i in range(1000000): z = return_list(2, 3, 4)
%prun for i in range(1000000): z = return_array(2, 3, 4)
```

The first one is executed in 0.32 seconds while the second one in 1.23 seconds. This tells me that it's the conversion of the list to a numpy array what takes most of the time. Is there a way to speed up this process? My return arrays are always small, 1x3, but I need to return an array, not a list.

Comment: Pretty sure there is no faster way. If you are given a list and need to do numpy stuff with it, eat the conversion time and get faster calculations. In this case, you're left with just eating the conversion time.

Comment: NumPy performance depends on performing operations on large arrays representing large amounts of data. If you make a separate array for each data point, you're not taking advantage of NumPy. It's like shipping 1000 packages in 1000 18-wheeler trucks instead of using 1 truck.

Comment: Array operations  are fast - once you have the arrays.  But if you are starting with lists, it often is faster to stick with list operations.  Many timing tests in SO questions have demonstrated that.

Comment: You can get a time gain of approximately 20-30 percent by using `njit` decorator from `numba` for your array case. `from numba import njit` and then put `@njit` just above `def return_array(x1, x2, x3):`. Overall it is still slower than `return_list`

Comment: Can you use an update pattern? fill_np_array(view_of_a_preallocated_array, x1, x2, x3) ?

Comment: @MihaiAndrei, that's what I ended up doing.